# Flutter converting a string into array

Tags: json, string, flutter

I am trying to change a long string text into an array, There are some methods in dart as String.split but its not working in Flutter, is there any solution that I can convert a string by spaces into an array and then use the array in a Listview

Comment: `split` is working in flutter - it uses dart after all

Comment: Thanks maybe I forgot to add dart Convert package in my code

Comment: Convert? `split()` is a `String` method, what does Convert has to do with it?

Comment: Oh I see that, I thought its from convert class :(

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After using `String.split` to create the `List` (the Dart equivalent of an Array), we have a `List<String>`. If you wanna use the `List<String>` inside a [ListView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html), you'll need a `Widget` which displays the text. You can simply use a [Text](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html) Widget.

The following functions can help you to do this:

1. `String.split`: To split the `String` to create the `List`
2. `List<String>.map`: Map the `String` to a Widget
3. `Iterable<Widget>.toList`: Convert the `Map` back to a `List`

Below a quick standalone example:

[image: Code Example]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String example = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: example
              .split(' ')                       // split the text into an array
              .map((String text) => Text(text)) // put the text inside a widget
              .toList(),                        // convert the iterable to a list
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that it is bit short and seems easier , I wrote it a little different

Comment: static List<String> Calories=name.split(" ");
final foods=List<String>.generate(15,(i)=> "${Myarray[i]}                 ${Calories[i]}");  body: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: foods.length,
  itemBuilder: (context,index){
    return ListTile(
title: Text('${foods[index]}'),

Comment: You may wanna add the code to your question, to clarify your goal and what you have tried!

Comment: Okay thank you very much, I wasnt aware of being able to add code into question cuz I am new in here, I will try to add in future

Comment: @Niklas, this is exactly what I'm looking for, but I'm trying to split a string everything 2 characters instead of by spaces. Any suggestions? Need this for Dart as well.

Comment: You could use RegEx and allMatches for splitting it every 2 characters. Or a simple for loop. I'd suggest you search google / whatever for some regex based solution. If you can't find any tell me again @JohnSmithly .

Answer (score 3):

For those who want to convert each character of string into list item, we can

```
 String username = "John Doe";

 List<String> searchKeywords = List<String>.generate(
          username.length,
          (index) => username[index]); // ['J','o','h','n',' ','D','o','e']
```

Morever you can remove white spaces using trim() method

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> list = "Hello Word".split("");
print(list);
//[H,e,l,l,o, ,W,o,r,l,d]


List<String> list = "Hello World".split(" ");
print(list);
//["Hello", "World"]
```